# "DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues" when i try to install node.js

Tags: node.js

when trying to install node.js `15.5.1` i get this error `(node:21252) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.` how can I correct for this? it opens a powershell and then after a bit it will give the error (I also cant ^C the thing it tells me to fix the code)